# Samsung AT Commands

Tags: android, communication, at-command

I have a Galaxy 5 (and also a Galaxy S3 mini), and I'm trying to create an application which makes a communication between the computer and the phone using AT Commands.

Does somebody have a list of these commands? Or I can use the generic ones (i.e. [this one](http://www.communica.se/multitech/gprs_at.pdf))?

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or **find** a book, tool, software library, tutorial or **other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow* ... SO is not human search engine, if you didn't find it with google it's prolly doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to implement standard AT commands, and not your own custom commands, then you should probably use the Hayes command set, which is the industry standard for communicating with modems. Sparkfun provides a great reference on this (via Tellit): https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Cellular%20Modules/AT_Commands_Reference_Guide_r0.pdf

I also found the website below to be useful; it provides a brief and concise overview of the Hayes modern command set: https://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kdenetwork/kppp/appendix-hayes-commands.html